# KVM: booting guest breaks network on host (still reachable within LAN, but no internet connectivity)

Tags: networking, kvm, qemu

After I updated the CPU (and BIOS) on my host, my current KVM setup is broken, and I cannot figure out why: ~10 seconds after my KVM guest is booted up, I'm unable to reach the internet from both the host or the clients. Connectivity within my LAN still seems to work (i.e., I'm still able to connect to host/server from within my LAN via ssh, existing VNC connection stays up).

## Before Starting VM

I'm running Debian 11 on my host, and have some Ubuntu kvm guests. Before booting up the guests (I'll just use one guest, `goingmerry`), everything works fine:

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.185.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s48-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.185.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from fra16s48-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.185.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from fra16s48-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.185.68): icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from fra16s48-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.185.68): icmp_seq=4 ttl=118 time=12.8 ms
```

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b30cdaf25b27
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
192.168.2.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp5s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

(you can see that the virtual network for the KVM has already started (`virbr0` in `route -n`).

## Once VM Is Started (Network is broken)

I then start up my KVM guest, and a very brief time after it is booted up everything is fine (I can connect via VNC or Spice, open the browser and visit websites) internet connectivity breaks on both host and client. E.g. on the host this happens:

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.185.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra24s06-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.100): icmp_seq=42 ttl=119 time=12.2 ms
[...snip ... ]
64 bytes from fra24s06-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.100): icmp_seq=68 ttl=119 time=12.5 ms
From myhost.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=69 Destination Host Unreachable
From myhost.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=70 Destination Host Unreachable
From myhost.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=71 Destination Host Unreachable
From myhost.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=72 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I have no idea why the ping message mentions `myhost.local` (where `myhost` is the hostname of my host) here.

Some other outputs from while the guest is running:

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.32
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    dns-nameserver 192.168.2.22
```

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 vnet0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 vnet0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b30cdaf25b27
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
192.168.2.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp5s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

```
# resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 192.168.2.2
       DNS Servers: 192.168.2.2
        DNS Domain: lan

Link 2 (enp5s0)
Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (br-b30cdaf25b27)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 5 (virbr0)
Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 6 (vnet0)
Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

```
olor]}
root@myhost:/home/tom# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:d9:f5:7d:c2:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.32/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6d9:f5ff:fe7d:c265/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br-b30cdaf25b27: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2f:43:d7:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-b30cdaf25b27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d1:c1:1e:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ca:96:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:a0:ac:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.254.122/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global vnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fea0:ac92/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is what I see on `var/log/syslog` while the guest is starting:

```
Oct 31 09:28:47 myhost kernel: [  518.943125] audit: type=1400 audit(1667204927.827:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-24a0099b-399b-4737-b766-6c64a25c18f7" pid=2946 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct 31 09:28:47 myhost kernel: [  519.075453] audit: type=1400 audit(1667204927.963:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-24a0099b-399b-4737-b766-6c64a25c18f7" pid=2949 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.204926] audit: type=1400 audit(1667204928.091:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-24a0099b-399b-4737-b766-6c64a25c18f7" pid=2953 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.316702] audit: type=1400 audit(1667204928.203:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-24a0099b-399b-4737-b766-6c64a25c18f7" pid=2957 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost systemd[1]: Started Virtual machine log manager.
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {create} index 6 type 1 <ETHER>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {update} flags 4098 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address EA:31:34:19:13:E9 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: Adding interface vnet0 [ ethernet ]
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 address 52:54:00:CA:96:BD mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {update} flags 69699 <UP,RUNNING,LOWER_UP>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.396033] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.397012] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.397019] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.397225] device vnet0 entered promiscuous mode
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.397767] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.397776] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered listening state
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost systemd-udevd[2968]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost systemd-udevd[2968]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {add} route fe80:: gw :: scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.499991] audit: type=1400 audit(1667204928.387:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-24a0099b-399b-4737-b766-6c64a25c18f7" pid=2979 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost systemd[1]: Started Virtual Machine qemu-1-goingmerry.
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.564602] audit: type=1400 audit(1667204928.451:18): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="libvirtd" pid=1350 comm="rpc-worker" capability=39  capname="bpf"
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost kernel: [  519.565110] audit: type=1400 audit(1667204928.451:19): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="libvirtd" pid=1350 comm="rpc-worker" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost libvirtd[2983]: 2022-10-31 08:28:48.458+0000: 2983: info : libvirt version: 7.0.0, package: 3 (Andrea Bolognani <eof@kiyuko.org> Fri, 26 Feb 2021 16:46:34 +0100)
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost libvirtd[2983]: 2022-10-31 08:28:48.458+0000: 2983: info : hostname: myhost
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost libvirtd[2983]: 2022-10-31 08:28:48.458+0000: 2983: warning : virSecurityValidateTimestamp:206 : Invalid XATTR timestamp detected on /srv/vm/lubuntu-1910.qcow2 secdriver=dac
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:48 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:50 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface vnet0.IPv6 with address fe80::fc54:ff:fea0:ac92.
Oct 31 09:28:50 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: New relevant interface vnet0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:28:50 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Registering new address record for fe80::fc54:ff:fea0:ac92 on vnet0.*.
Oct 31 09:28:50 myhost kernel: [  521.411396] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered learning state
Oct 31 09:28:50 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:50 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:52 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:52 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:52 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {update} flags 69699 <UP,RUNNING,LOWER_UP>
Oct 31 09:28:52 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 address 52:54:00:CA:96:BD mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:52 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 operstate 6 <UP>
Oct 31 09:28:52 myhost kernel: [  523.427132] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered forwarding state
Oct 31 09:28:52 myhost kernel: [  523.427136] virbr0: topology change detected, propagating
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {RX} 0 packets 0 bytes
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {TX} 1 packets 590 bytes
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {RX} 0 packets 0 bytes
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {TX} 1 packets 590 bytes
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {RX} 0 packets 0 bytes
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {TX} 1 packets 590 bytes
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:28:55 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 0 <UNKNOWN>
Oct 31 09:28:57 myhost dnsmasq-dhcp[2932]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.208 52:54:00:a0:ac:92 
Oct 31 09:28:57 myhost dnsmasq-dhcp[2932]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.208 52:54:00:a0:ac:92 goingmerry
Oct 31 09:29:28 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface vnet0.IPv4 with address 169.254.254.122.
Oct 31 09:29:28 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: New relevant interface vnet0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:29:28 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Registering new address record for 169.254.254.122 on vnet0.IPv4.
Oct 31 09:29:28 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {add} address 169.254.254.122/16 label vnet0 family 2
Oct 31 09:29:28 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {add} route 169.254.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
Oct 31 09:29:28 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
```

## Shutting down VM.

As soon as I shut down the KVM guest, connectivity is restored on the host:

```
$ ping www.google.com
                             
PING www.google.com (142.250.186.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
From serenity.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
[...snip...]
From serenity.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=53 Destination Host Unreachable
From serenity.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=54 Destination Host Unreachable
From serenity.local (169.254.254.122) icmp_seq=55 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from fra24s06-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.100): icmp_seq=57 ttl=119 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from fra24s06-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.100): icmp_seq=58 ttl=119 time=12.4 ms
64 bytes from fra24s06-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.100): icmp_seq=59 ttl=119 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from fra24s06-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.100): icmp_seq=60 ttl=119 time=12.5 ms
```

```
# tail /var/log/syslog

Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Interface vnet0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost kernel: [ 1976.540921] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost kernel: [ 1976.541608] device vnet0 left promiscuous mode
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost kernel: [ 1976.541616] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface vnet0.IPv6 with address fe80::fc54:ff:fea0:ac92.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {RX} 176 packets 28758 bytes
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {TX} 1332 packets 162018 bytes
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {update} flags 4098 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Interface vnet0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface vnet0.IPv4 with address 169.254.254.122.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::fc54:ff:fea0:ac92 on vnet0.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.254.122 on vnet0.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: Removing default interface route failed (No such device)
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: Removing default interface route failed (No such device)
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: Removing default interface route failed (No such device)
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Withdrawing address record for ::1 on lo.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Interface lo.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6d9:f5ff:fe7d:c265 on enp5s0.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp5s0.IPv6 with address fe80::6d9:f5ff:fe7d:c265.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Interface enp5s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: New relevant interface lo.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Registering new address record for ::1 on lo.*.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: (null) {del} route fe80:: gw :: scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: (null) {del} address 169.254.254.122/16 label vnet0
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 address FE:54:00:A0:AC:92 mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {newlink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {dellink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: (null) {remove} index 6
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: Remove interface (null) [ ethernet ]
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {RX} 176 packets 26294 bytes
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {TX} 165 packets 47346 bytes
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {update} flags 4163 <UP,RUNNING>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 address 52:54:00:CA:96:BD mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 operstate 6 <UP>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: vnet0 {dellink} index 6 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {RX} 176 packets 26294 bytes
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {TX} 165 packets 47346 bytes
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {update} flags 4099 <UP>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 address 52:54:00:CA:96:BD mtu 1500
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: virbr0 {newlink} index 5 operstate 2 <DOWN>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: enp5s0 {del} route fe80:: gw :: scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost connmand[1223]: enp5s0 {add} route fe80:: gw :: scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost systemd[1]: machine-qemu\x2d1\x2dgoingmerry.scope: Succeeded.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost systemd[1]: machine-qemu\x2d1\x2dgoingmerry.scope: Consumed 1min 29.000s CPU time.
Oct 31 09:53:05 myhost kernel: [ 1976.813274] audit: type=1400 audit(1667206385.703:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-24a0099b-399b-4737-b766-6c64a25c18f7" pid=3352 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct 31 09:53:06 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp5s0.IPv6 with address fe80::6d9:f5ff:fe7d:c265.
Oct 31 09:53:06 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: New relevant interface enp5s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 31 09:53:06 myhost avahi-daemon[1220]: Registering new address record for fe80::6d9:f5ff:fe7d:c265 on enp5s0.*.
```

I'm at a complete loss here, no idea what's going on or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the host's `DNS` is configured to resolve on `KVM`, or is there some connection between them, I found that they resolve to different `IP` addresses, and when you turn off `KVM`, the host uses the default `DNS`, just guessing, I don't know what the problem is

Comment: I had a similar feeling, since the ping suddenly fails at `myhost.local`, which seems weird. But the output of `resolvectl status` shown above shows that the DNS seems to point to 192.168.2.2, which is correct. How else could I check for this?